# How to set each item of a asp:CheckBoxList to seperate row of a bootstrap datatable ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, checkboxlist

I have a **asp:CheckBoxList** to my .aspx page. I want each item of that **asp:CheckBoxList** as seperate row of bootstrap dataTable. My code is like below

```
<asp:table id="tblUserToRoleList">
   <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>
          Role List
        </th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
           <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkRoleList" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:CheckBoxList>
         </td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

and the output like this
 [image]

here all the items are in under one **td** of single **tr**

But i need all that items to separate **tr** for which i can search items from **bootstrap dataTable**'s default search box

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<asp:CheckBoxList>` generates an HTML table.The problem is that this table doesn't have `<th>` elements defined and the Bootstrap DataTable **requires** these tags to be present.

Solution?Manually add the `<th>` tags **before** calling DataTable();

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            debugger;
            $("<thead><tr><th>Roles</th></tr><thead>").insertBefore("#chkRoleList tbody");
            $('#chkRoleList').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkRoleList" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:CheckBoxList>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Output:**
[image: Bootstrap DataTable searching]

Comment: This is exactly that i was looking for.